# How Is つ/ツ origin 川?

Tags: etymology, kana

Wikipedia's [Tsu (kana)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsu_%28kana%29) page says

[image: tsu]

> つ/ツ
>
> hiragana origin    川
>
> katakana origin    川

- How Is つ/ツ origin 川?

Answer (score 5):

That is because the cursive script of the kanji 「川」 kind of looks like 「つ」.  It should look even more like 「ツ」.

[image]
<sub>(source: [netdna-ssl.com](https://bcpzone-tsttechnology.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/figure_3_4_hiragana_tsu-horz.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Does this also mean then that 川 used to represent 「tsu」originally in writing?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's one of characters used to represent "**tu**".

Comment: @broccoliforest:  What does your comment mean?

Comment: @istrasci At the time hiragana and katakana developed, Japanese *tu* had not yet assibilated to *tsu*.  That occurred hundreds of years later.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually three candidates for the origin of つ and ツ.

One is 州, which in the [Jiankang dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go-on) was pronounced "zhōu". Zhōu → tsu (origin of kana) → shuu (modern on'yomi).

The next is 川, which is generally pronounced "chuan" in Chinese. Chuan → tsuan → tsu (origin of kana) → sen (modern on'yomi).

Yet another argument is that the kana are derived from the kun'yomi of 州, which today is pronounced "su".

The way the hiragana is written might be a calligraphic form of either 州 or 川.